# Beginner BlackJack Game

Tags: c++, blackjack

I am currently switching languages from Java(beginner) to c++ and would like to replicate a BlackJack game I made in Java but am having difficulty with the set up in C++ using codeblocks.

Code Design:

- enum's of Rank and Suit.
- The 52 variations of Rank and Suit are formed together to create 52 objects of Card
- Store the objects in a vector
- Randomise Vector
- Pop two cards from Vector to Player
- Pop one card to Dealer
- When the player or dealer is dealt a card, the card retrieved is calculated and value += to  int player/dealerValue;

I am lost as to how I can achieve this:

Deck.cpp:

```
     for(Suit suit: Suit.values()) {
        for (Rank rank : Rank.values()) {   
           add(new Card(rank, suit));   
        }
    }
     createDeck()
     shuffleDeck()
     dealUser()
     dealerDealer()
```

Player.cpp

```
     userVector
     dealerVector
     getUserVector()
     getDealerVector()
     addCardUser()
     addCardDealer()
     calcUserValue()
     calcDealerValue()
```

Card.cpp

```
     card(Rank rank, Suit suit) { }
     getSuit()
     getRank()
```

BlackJack.cpp

```
    call deck constructor
    Player user  =  new Player()
    Player dealer = new Player()
```

---Game Code---

Could someone please cover or direct me to some good resources for:

- Managing header files
- Brief skeleton code blocks for some of the methods I require
- But most importantly, will I be required to use pointers at all for this program? I've only had access to online YouTube tutorials for a few days now while my c++ books arrive and am not yet confident with memory management of any kind.
- Any general c++ tips for this program would be fantastic.

Many thanks for your time and patience to read this.

Comment: This is a bit too broad as written. If you want to ask one specific question at a time, we'd love to help, provided that the question is not open ended and can have a single correct answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To address your points:

### Managing header files

Don't bother. Just throw everything in one source file (you're perfectly allowed to do this in C++, unlike Java). Maybe sometime later you can break it up into more than one source file, if you want.

### Skeleton code blocks for methods

If you've already got the code written in Java, then there's your skeleton blocks.

### Do I have to use pointers?

Probably not. However, if you just want to get started with a program that looks like your Java code, you can always simply ignore manual memory management, call `new`, and never worry about `delete`. You'll have memory leaks all over the place, but one thing at a time, right?

Typical "modern" C++ style avoids the use of raw pointers almost entirely. You can work on that at some later time.

Comment: Thank you, I wasn't aware it all being in one file was acceptable. What resources do I need to read up on to avoid memory leaks? I would like to attempt to avoid bad coding habits (new etc). In the context of this program, where will I be using pointers?  Lastly, are enums used differently in c++? Any chance you could post up how you would generate 52 cards from Rank enum and Suit enum? I've got the Java code but don't know how it would translate. Thanks a bunch again, appreciate it.

Comment: The use of `new` is not a "bad coding habit" by itself. Dynamic memory allocation is an integral part of most modern programming systems. I don't know where you might want to use pointers, but you can pretty much translate your Java code to C++ by using a pointer wherever you use a reference in Java. It depends on what your goal is - do you want to simply start writing code in C++, or do you want to abandon what you know about Java and start over with C++? (I would suggest just getting something running so you can play with it.)

Comment: Here's how to convert your Java code to C++: `Player user = new Player()` -> `Player *user = new Player()`; `user.method()` -> `user->method()`. You can get a long way with that.

Comment: I begun learning Java in University last academic year. But the way it was taught coupled with the way I approached it was very very counter productive. I learnt terrible habbits, didn't 'LEARN' programming. So I am trying to distance my self from Java and focus on C++ and truly learn it form the ground up. Do you have any tips on how I can avoid the issue I faced when learning Java when I learn C++? I've ordered Accelerated C++ but apart from that I don't know what to do. Thank you. 

Just seen your post above, just what I wanted, thank you for that snippet.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know what "issue" you faced when learning Java, so it's hard for me to offer suggestions for avoiding that issue. Get a good book (I don't know anything specifically about "Accelerated C++"), do the exercises, and have fun.

Comment: If you started learning C++ from scratch again tomorrow, how would you approach it? I've ordered books, have project ideas but really want to storm through as much coding as possible as time is of the essence to get somewhat comfortable with c++ to bring it up to my knowledge of Java.

Comment: The way I prefer to learn new programming languages is to get the canonical book on the language, usually written by the author of the language itself, and read that cover to cover. For C++ that would be ["The C++ Programming Language" by Bjarne Stroustrup](http://www.amazon.com/C-Programming-Language-Third/dp/0201889544). However, everybody learns differently and I'm no expert on teaching.

Answer (score 1):

I'm approaching this from the "learning by doing is better" perspective... so the aim of this answer is to get you on track so you can start experimenting.

1. **Design**: Both languages are very similar, so the classes and class structure do not matter regardless of Java or C++, so you can continue thinking "in Java terms" when you're working with C++. You can just start with the same design.
2. **organization of files**: Think of a .java file as corresponding to a .h file and a .cpp file pair (not always true, and the extensions may differ according to preference, but this will do for now). Copy the Java code into the .h header file and isolate the function definitions into the corresponding .cpp file. The usual syntactic cleanup is necessary - subbing out imports into `#include<header.h>` definitions, prefixing function definitions with the class name (remember to use the `ClassName::` syntax). Also remember that including the header files does not mean you're including the context - you will still need to refer to it using the appropriate namespace. **Note**: This step *will* produce compilation errors, but that's probably the best way to learn and get used to the differences.
3. **memory management**: On your Q pointers, good C++ programming convention denotes: *pointers = no-no, stack variables and smart pointers=yes-yes*. Use stack variables for normal / temporary variables. For parameters etc, use `boost::shared_pointer` (download and install the [boost libraries](http://www.boost.org/)). It's usage is just like a normal C++ pointer (i.e. uses `newlyDealtCard->member` syntax). The reason in a nutshell is that the shared pointer mimics the Java object model - object assignment creates references instead of copies, and the object is auto-deleted when all references go out of use. 99 out of 100 times, the behavior is the same and it will save you time that you can spend on understanding other things. Once you're comfortable with how C++ represents and handles memory, you can start using other smart pointer types.
   Syntax:

   Card newlydealtCard = new Card(randomSuite, randomValue); //Java

   boost::shared_pointer newlydealtCard(new Card(randomSuite, randomValue)); //C++
4. **Inheritance**:
   For `interface`s, use the keyword `class`. And declare the functions [pure virtual](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_function#Abstract_classes_and_pure_virtual_functions).
   When deriving from these 'interfaces' or other classes, use public inheritance for now. There are two other type in C++ that you can start looking up once you've become more comfortable.

The rest of the differences are mostly syntactic or are just differently-named standard functions, they don't involve a change of perspective. Hopefully, as you code more, you'll be able to explore outside these options.

Good luck!

Comment: Just seen this comment, thank you very much for your input, some great information!